# Convert string to time c#

Tags: c#, .net, string, datetime

I would like to do a c# app which it does a if logical operation to verify if the time coincides with business hours. I tried to use this code below, but it show me an error

```
DateTime data = DateTime.Parse(txt_Hora.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
if (data > "09:00")
{
    MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO produtos_pedidos (quantidade, data_pedido, subtotal, hora) VALUES ('" + cmb_Quantidade.Text + "','" + txt_Data.Text + "','" + lbl_Subtotal.Text + "','" + txt_Hora.Text + "')", bdcon);
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Reservado com sucesso");
}
```

Here's the error: The operator ">" can't be apply to DateTime type and string type

Comment: With `data > "09:00"` you compare 2 data types: `DateTime` and `string`. There is no implicit conversation for these, you'd have to create comparable values. Try `data.Hour > 9` instead to compare an hour

Comment: Before you tackle that, fix your SQL. Do not concat your SQL. You are wide open to SQL Injection attacks!

Comment: Don't use string concatenation to construct SQL statements. This exposes you to SQL Injection attacks and conversion errors like this one. Use parameterized queries instead. Imagine what would happen if one of those text fields contained `'); DROP TABLE Users;--`

Comment: I didn´t know about his one, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like:

```
if (data.TimeOfDay > new TimeSpan(0, 9, 0, 0))
{
   // Whatever
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use string concatenation to construct SQL statements. This exposes you to SQL Injection attacks and conversion errors like this one. Use parameterized queries instead :

```
var sql="INSERT INTO produtos_pedidos (quantidade, data_pedido, subtotal, hora) VALUES (@quant,@data,@total,@hora)";


using var cmd=new MySqlCommand(sql, bdcon);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quant",quant);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data",pedido);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total",total);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hora",hora);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Parse the text values into the proper type before using them. If possible, use UI elements that provide the type you want. If you use a combo with values or products, bind its value to the actual ID or quantity and use that value instead of the string label. If you want to pick a time, [use a DateTimePicker set to work as a TimePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-display-time-with-the-datetimepicker-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&redirectedfrom=MSDN), eg :

```
var quant=(int)cmb_Quantidade.SelectedValue;
var data=txt_Data.Text ;
var total=decimal.Parse(lbl_Subtotal.Text);
var hora=timePicker.Value.Time;
```

The time of day is represented by the `TimeSpan` type. The time of day of a `DateTime` is returned by the `TimeOfDay` property. If you can't use a DateTimePicker (why?) you need to parse the data into a TimeSpan:

```
var hora=TimeSpan.Parse(txt_Hora.Text);
```

Putting it all together :

```
var quant=(int)cmb_Quantidade.SelectedValue;
var data=txt_Data.Text;
var total=decimal.Parse(lbl_Subtotal.Text);
var hora=timePicker.Value.Time;

if (hora>TimeSpan.FromHours(9))
{
    using var cmd=new MySqlCommand(sql, bdcon);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quant",quant);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pedido",pedido);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total",total);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hora",hora);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, didn't know about the SQL Injection that you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

> Convert string to time c#

Use time span for comparison

```
TimeSpan timeSpan = new TimeSpan(
    0, 
    data.Hour, 
    data.Minute, 
    data.Second, 
    data.Millisecond);

var ttt = timeSpan.ToString();

TimeSpan timeSpan2 = new TimeSpan(0, 9, 0, 0, 0); // "09:00"

if (timeSpan > timeSpan2)
{
    ... //Your code
}
```

Or simply

```
if (data.TimeOfDay > new TimeSpan(0, 9, 0, 0, 0))
{
    ... //Your code
}
```

Or

```
if (data.TimeOfDay > TimeSpan.Parse("09:00"))
{
    ... //Your code
}
```

Comment: I tried the 3st option and worked, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

1st you are comparing DateTime to string, so make a `DateTime.Parse("09:00")` as you did on the first line to have a datetime that can be compared to the `data` variable

2nd, to compare 2 DateTime variables use [DateTime.Compare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.compare?view=net-6.0) instead of > operation as the error massage advises.

Comment: Woth to note that `DateTime.Parse("09:00")` returns a datetime with the current date like `Thursday, 02 June 2022 09:00`. Also, dates are compared as well, not only the time

Answer (score -2):

Just work with two `TimeSpan`

```
TimeSpan timeOfTheDay = TimeSpan.Parse(txt_Hora.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
if (timeOfTheDay > new TimeSpan(9,0,0))
    ...
```

Comment: Almost every possible date value is after `0001-01-01 09:00:00`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos. edited. I was assuming that txt_Hora.Text (Hora = time - or hour - in Spanish) is expected to be a string such  11:23
Using `TimeSpan`, and `TimeSpan.Parse` as well, is the way to go

Comment: It's not Spanish haha, it's portuguese, but thanks for the answer!